# Default printing options in KDE 4 dialog

Tags: kde, printing

How can I set default printing options, so that they are always pre-populated in the KDE 4 print dialog window (when printing from Okular for example)?

EDIT: In particular I would like to set duplex printing and printing colour as grey to be default parameters.

Comment: have you tried editing/creating the file `/home/$USER/.cups/lpoptions`, and puting a line `Default <printer name>` in there ?

Comment: I did set up the default CUPS options (using some dialog boxes, can't remember which ones) - and I can see those when printing from non-KDE applications (e.g. acroread). However, KDE seems to ignore these.

Comment: @VincentNivoliers, I am more after setting two sided printing and print colour as grey in the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Install the package `system-config-printer-kde.` That application will allow you to add/configure printers. I think you can set it here.

#### References

- [Print Settings with CUPS](http://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Print_Settings_with_CUPS#Different_default_paper_size_settings)
- [print-manager-updates-in-kde-4-11](http://dantti.wordpress.com/2013/05/28/print-manager-updates-in-kde-4-11/)

Comment: fwiw, the KDE Plasma 5 package corresponding to `system-config-printer-kde` is called `print-manager` (afaik)